# React Native Error : Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create a pin lock screen. The problem occured in the num pads section.it said "**Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**" I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

here is my list for the number pads.

```
render() {
        let numberPads = [
            {id: 1,value: '1', style: styles.numPad},
            { id: 2,value: '2', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 3,value: '3', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 4,value: '4', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 5,value: '5', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 6,value: '6', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 7,value: '7', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 8,value: '8', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 9,value: '9', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 10,value: '', style: styles.keyPad },
            { id: 11,value: '0', style: styles.numPad },
            { id: 12,value: '11', style: styles.keyPad }
        ]
        return (........) }
```

here is how the number pads above is rendered.

```
render(){
   ......
   return(
   .....
   <View style={styles.numPadContainer}>
     {numberPads.map(numberPad => {
             let numPad = numberPad.id != 12 ?
                   <TouchableOpacity style={numberPad.style} key={numberPad.id}
                    onPress={() => this.onPressNumberPad(numberPad.value)}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.numText} >{numberPad.value}</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity> :
                   <TouchableOpacity style={numberPad.style} key={numberPad.id}
                    onPress={() => this.onPressDeletePad()}
                    >
                         <Image  source={require('../assets/images/clear-icon-50px.png')} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    return (
                             numPad
                    )
       })}
    </View>
    ......
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code above is no problem, I think.
It may have in another place in your code that you didn't show all.
Check your code again or show all the error log here.

Comment: Yes you're right. I happened to have another map() in  my code. after a careful error log examination, I've found that the warning indicated to that map() instead of this one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The **children in the TouchableOpacity must have a key props too**.

You can find more information in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js).

Answer (score 0):

Each Flatlist item must have unique identity to avoid duplicity

Use keyExtractor property of Flatlist, it will resolve your issue

```
<FlatList 
    data={ props.data }
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Item tittle = { item }  />}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
render(){
   ......
   return(
   .....
   <View style={styles.numPadContainer}>
     {numberPads.map((numberPad,index) => {
             let numPad = numberPad.id != 12 ?
                   <TouchableOpacity style={numberPad.style} key={numberPad.id.toString()}
                    onPress={() => this.onPressNumberPad(numberPad.value)}
                    >
                        <Text style={styles.numText} >{numberPad.value}</Text>
                   </TouchableOpacity> :
                   <TouchableOpacity style={numberPad.style} key={numberPad.id.toString()}
                    onPress={() => this.onPressDeletePad()}
                    >
                         <Image  source={require('../assets/images/clear-icon-50px.png')} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    return (
                             numPad
                    )
       })}
    </View>
    ......
    )
}
```